# ElectronJS | How to translate browser window on hover?

Tags: html, css, electron

I'm working on an Electron app, attempting to create a sidebar. At first, only the arrow should be showing, while the rest of it is off the screen. When a user hovers over the arrow (displayed below), I want it to pull out the rest of the sidebar to be used by the user. However, I'm having a problem where because the browser window size remains the same, the css hover animation goes off the browser window and disappears. How can I translate the browser window on hover? Or if there is a better solution, please provide it.

Current Progress

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Animating the size of the application window to display any extra content, in this case, your side menu is not a standard UI interaction. If the users window is maximised or full screen, the the side menu would not display anyway as it would be out of bounds of the screen / monitor. I suggest animating the side menu inwards from the edge of the  window. There are plenty of examples online to implement this type of slide in  type of menu just using HTML, CSS and even a little bit of JavaScript if needed.